# Get current URL in Twisted

Tags: python, url, twisted, vps

I wrote a script in twisted that proxies websites, and I'm just wondering if there's a way to get the current url in Twisted? or even let me know when the URL changes? Thanks!

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import proxy, server
site = server.Site(proxy.ReverseProxyResource('www.website.com', 80, ''.encode("utf-8")))
reactor.listenTCP(80, site)
reactor.run()
```